# python selenium how to execute_script only when function is available

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to do
`driver.execute_script('getDate();')`

This function `getDate()` is defined in the javascript of the webpage. How to make sure that the function definition has loaded first? Otherwise I get an error saying `javascript error: no such function...`

Update: My use case is that there is a datepicker element that calls this function at some point. I would like to directly get/set the date with this function rather that writing code to find the datepicker element, click on day,month,year etc which I feel would be complicated

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: Just curious how that information would help with the solution? If it helps there is basically a datepicker element that calls this function at some point. I would like to directly  get/set the date with this function rather that writing code to find the datepicker element, click on day,month,year etc which I feel would be complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a wait until with the following:

```
// waituntil
while (typeof getDate !== "function") {
  task(i); // timeout
}

function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      // Add tasks to do
  }, 2000 * i);
}

// now call getDate
getDate();
```

Comment: Thanks but I think this would just skip calling the function if it doesn't exist yet? I would like to wait until the function exists and then call it before moving forward.

Comment: i see, that was not clear for me. i will later adjust that answer

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer